# How to make dynamically added list items draggable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fileToUpload").live("change", function () {
        ajaxFileUpload();
    });
});

function ajaxFileUpload() {

    var FileFolder = "myimages/";
    var fileToUpload = getNameFromPath($('#fileToUpload').val());
    var filename = fileToUpload.substr(0, (fileToUpload.lastIndexOf('.')));
    if (checkFileExtension(fileToUpload)) {


        $.ajaxFileUpload({
            url: 'FileUpload.ashx',
            secureuri: false,
            fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, status) {
                ShowUploadedFiles(data);
                if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {

                    if (data.error != '') {
                        alert(data.error);
                    } else {
                        ShowUploadedFiles(data.upfile, filename);
                        $('#fileToUpload').val("");
                        alert("File uploaded succesfully");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (data, status, e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('You can upload only jpg,jpeg extensions files.');
    }
    return false;

}

function ShowUploadedFiles(data) {
    $("ul.gallery").append("<li class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr'> <h5 class='ui-widget-header'>Rana Saif</h5><img src='" + data + "' width='96';height='72' /><a href='" + data + "'  class='ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin'>View larger</a><a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a></li>");

}

$(function () {
    // there's the gallery and the trash
    var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
        $trash = $("#trash");

    // let the gallery items be draggable
    $("li", $gallery).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
    $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
    $gallery.droppable({
        accept: "#trash li",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    // image deletion function
    var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

    function deleteImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function () {
            var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ? $("ul", $trash) : $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);

            $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
            $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function () {
                $item.animate({
                    width: "48px"
                })
                    .find("img")
                    .animate({
                    height: "36px"
                });
            });
        });
    }

    // image recycle function
    var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

    function recycleImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function () {
            $item.find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
                .remove()
                .end()
                .css("width", "96px")
                .append(trash_icon)
                .find("img")
                .css("height", "72px")
                .end()
                .appendTo($gallery)
                .fadeIn();
        });
    }

    // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
    function viewLargerImage($link) {
        var src = $link.attr("href"),
            title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
            $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

        if ($modal.length) {
            $modal.dialog("open");
        } else {
            var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
                .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
            setTimeout(function () {
                img.dialog({
                    title: title,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true
                });
            }, 1);
        }
    }

    // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
    $("ul.gallery > li").click(function (event) {
        var $item = $(this),
            $target = $(event.target);

        if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
            deleteImage($item);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
            viewLargerImage($target);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
            recycleImage($item);
        }

        return false;
    });
});

function checkFileExtension(file) {
    var flag = true;
    var extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
    switch (extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
            flag = true;
            break;
        default:
            flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
}



function getNameFromPath(strFilepath) {

    var objRE = new RegExp(/([^\/\\]+)$/);
    var strName = objRE.exec(strFilepath);

    if (strName == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return strName[0];
    }

}
```

On document ready ajaxFileUpload() function is calling which uploads a picture on server through generic handler and returns image path and on success another
function ShowUploadedFiles() is calling which appends list item. Here images are visible but unable to drag these.
Kindly tell me how I make these elements draggable?

Comment: after those items are added to the dom you need to initialize the draggable widget for them

Comment: too much code to go through and see what is happening

Comment: I initialize the draggable widget where I am appending list items and now it works fine. Thanks Arun P Johny.